# CompletableFuture.allOf() doesn’t wait untill all the runs are completed

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, completable-future

Hi I am bit new to async programming and CompletableFuture. I want to run a list of task in asynchronously (using CompletableFuture) and update the result to multiple objects.
Once all the tasks in the list updates the objects, I want my method to execute next lines synchronously.

I tried CompletableFuture.allOf() which Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures are complete.

But in my case, I get it before all of the given CompletableFutures are complete. Please guide me if I am missing anything.

```
List<MyData> data =  getFromAMethod();
OutputObject  outputObject = new OutputObject();
List<AnotherValue> valueList1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Value> valueList2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (MyData data : dataList) {
 CompletableFuture<Void> requestCompletableFuture =
     CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
             () -> executeMyMethod(data))
         .exceptionally(throwable -> {
               throw  new SomeCustomException<>();
         })
         .thenAccept(
             outputFromMyMethod -> {

               if(outputObject.getSomeField()==null){
                 outputObject,setSomeField(outputFromMyMethod.getField);
               }
                 valueList1.add(outputFromMyMethod.getValue1());
                 valueList2.add(outputFromMyMethod.getValue2());

             });
 completableFutures.add(requestCompletableFuture);
}

CompletableFuture<Void> allOfcompletableFuture =
   CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

allOfcompletableFuture
   .whenComplete(
       (result, exception) -> {
         if (exception != null) {
           throw new SomeCustomException();
         } else {
          outputObject.setValueList1(valueList1);
          outputObject.setValueList2(valueList2);
         }
       })
   .join();

//  next lines will be executed by main thread
taskOutput.setDisplayOutputs(ffxFeeDisplayOutputList);
```

In most of the runs valueList1 and valueList2 will not be getting updated with all the values, also I am not having any exceptions during these run.
I have also tried with **get()** method call after **whenComplete** still I am facing same issue.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Sharing one ArrayList among several threads looks very suspicious and could be your problem. Try using a CopyOnWriteArrayList to see if it solves your problem. And if that works and performance is important, you could also use an array since you know the final size. But start with a concurrent list to check correctness.

Comment: @assylias yes passing ArrayList was the issue. CopyOnWriteArrayList worked for me. Since it is expensive I used an array. Thanks